# Show more/less on value that already set in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I want to make a show more & show less on a product.description, however when I test on normal string is working but on the value with {{product.description}} it will hidden the whole value in {{product.description}} with a "Show More" when click on it will display whole description and "Show Less" when click on it will hidden whole description again.

For example: Normal string 
abc..... more
abcdef   less
abc..... more

But on {{product.description}}
...... more
abcdef less
...... more

The product.description value is already set in the system...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var showChar = 100;
  var ellipsestext = "...";
  var moretext = "more";
  var lesstext = "less";
  $('.more').each(function() {
    var content = $(this).html();

    if (content.length > showChar) {

      var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
      var h = content.substr(showChar - 1, content.length - showChar);
      var charac = content.length;
      var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext + charac + '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';

      $(this).html(html);
    }

  });

  $(".morelink").click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("less")) {
      $(this).removeClass("less");
      $(this).html(moretext);
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("less");
      $(this).html(lesstext);
    }
    $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
    $(this).prev().toggle();
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
.morecontent span {
  display: none;
}

.comment {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="comment more">
  <p> {{ product.description }} </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm guessing you should choose between angular and angularjs and perhaps jquery for that matter..

Comment: Why do u even want to use jquery? Try and implement it in angular, As your project is in angular. Using jQuery in Angular projects is really a bad idea

Answer (score 0):

set the number of item to show ie.show less or more by setting the length.I suggest use angular js properly.

```
 example:

<p>{{showContent}}</p>
<button ng-click="shwMoreOrLess()">{{buttonName}}</button>
var a = "your string of 100 char";
$scope.showContent = a;//default
$scope.buttonName = "Show Less";//default
$scope.shwMoreOrLess = function(){
   var length = ($scope.buttonName = "Show More" ) ? 100 : 50;//setting length of the string. 
   $scope.showContent = a.slice(0, length);
   $scope.buttonName = ($scope.buttonName = "Show More" ) ? "Show Less" : "Show More";
//your code goes here...
}
```